# App is Listening, No Iptables, Yet Port is Closed

Tags: linux, tcp

I have an application that is listening on port 7077 on a server:

```
netstat -a -W | grep 7077
tcp6       0      0 spartacus.servile.war:7077 [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

I can connect to the port with telnet on "spartacus", and can run a client program using the port on "spartacus" also, but I **cannot** connect to 7077 from another computer on the same LAN with telnet or a client program.

Spartacus is running xubuntu 12.04, iptables is not installed.
If I run nmap port 7077 is closed:

```
nmap -p 7077 192.168.0.113
Nmap scan report for Spartacus.servile.war (192.168.0.113)
Host is up (0.000061s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
7077/tcp closed unknown
```

nmap also reports that this port has no filtering:

```
nmap -sA -p 7077 192.168.0.113
Nmap scan report for Spartacus.servile.war (192.168.0.113)
PORT     STATE      SERVICE
7077/tcp unfiltered unknown
```

For what it's worth, running traceroute on the other machine gives this:

```
$ traceroute -p 7077 192.168.0.113
traceroute to 192.168.0.113 (192.168.0.113), 64 hops max
  1   192.168.0.113  0.243ms  0.140ms  0.161ms
```

Why is port 7077 not open, and how can I open it?

I have Googled extensively but results either want to HELP me close ports, or assume I have iptables running, or think I want to find an app that is listening, or... (the list goes on) but not this situation.

The app is Spark Master 1.3.1, but this is not a Spark issue, I am (almost completely) sure.

Comment: Did you try tcpdump while your app is running and listening on port 7077 and attempting to connect to it from another machine.  `tcpdump -vv port 7077`

Comment: Is this only a tcp6 connection? Where is tcp4? "tcp6   0 0 spartacus.servile.war:7077 [::]:*  LISTEN"

Comment: tcpdump shows a syn, reset connection exchange: Lord-Linux.servile.war.39249 > Spartacus.servile.war.7077: Flags [S]; Spartacus.servile.war.7077 > Lord-Linux.servile.war.39249: Flags [R.] There are no tcp4 connections showing with netstat -a. What to do to fix?

Comment: Disabling ipv6 on the server cause the app to listen on tcp, instead of tcp6, but that changes no behaviors. Port is still closed but unfiltered, I can connect on the same server, but not over the LAN, tcpdump behavior is the same. I found that Ubuntu distribs have a firewall named ufw, but that is disabled also.  Everything I can find about a "closed port" asserts that a firewall is blocking, or there is nothing listening, but neither condition applies here. What other thing causes a closed port?

Comment: I found the problem: netstat -t -n, shows:
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:7077          127.0.0.1:46335         ESTABLISHED

Comment: I found the problem: netstat -t -n, shows the process show by its FQDN was not attaching to its network IP, but to 127.0.1.1, which it appears is a kludge put into Debian based installers, to fix a potential bug (and thus creating new bugs, like this). I deleted the line from /etc/hosts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by the problem for a whole day, but I fixed it just now, you can cat /etc/hosts, you can modify the second line of this file to your local ip, then it works. I don't know why that works, but it do.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).